# Fetching and combining field values from vector layer to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, vector-layer

I have two different layers: one is a vector "polygon" layer, and the other is a vector "point" layer.

I have information (address and number) in my point layer that I would like to import into my "polygon" layer. The names of my fields are not necessarily the same, but my points are always located inside the respective polygons where the addresses and street numbers must coincide.

Is there a  QGIS tool / way that can import the values of my fields from my respective point layer into my polygon layer (i.e. number -> number and address -> address) for all points and polygons that overlap?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributesbylocation) tool:

> Takes an input vector layer and creates a new vector layer that is an
> extended version of the input one, with additional attributes in its
> attribute table.

Comment: wonderfull! thanks a lot :)